# How to compile a CUDA project with my own Makefile from inside Nsight?

Tags: cuda, icc, nsight, intel-mkl, makefile

I have a CUDA project which contains .c and .cu files. The project also uses MKL. Currently I compile the project without problems using my own makefile from terminal. This makefile uses both the Intel C Compiler (icc 15.0.0) and CUDA 6.0 compiler (nvcc).

I would like to build the project from inside NSight but I cannot find the right way. I have tried  to configure the build which is provided with NSight to use my onwn Makefile without success.

I have achieved to generate a project with a default build (make all) from inside NSight. However I do not know how to customize the default build to my own Makefile.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nsight is based on CDT so [this tutorial](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Fgetting_started%2Fcdt_w_import.htm) should work. If you have any CUDA C sources, use "CUDA C" project wizard and select CUDA Toolkit as a toolchain.